# Xcode displaying odd shaped views

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

My views in Xcode (Xcode 6) are all oddly sized (some tall, some short) and are looking very out of place when I run them in the emu. Ill show you some pictures as I'm not doing a very good job at explaining it.

[image: Xcode displaying views odly]

As you can see, theres a white part at the bottom which is un-fillable and the content (which should be under the nav-bar) is being shown perfectly in the emu.

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Is it a bug in Xcode 6?

Comment: Side note - I assume by "emu" you mean emulator. There is no emulator, it's a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect or missing launch images will cause this behavior. Remove your existing launch images or add the correctly sized launch image for iPhone 5S.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Never touched launch images before.

Comment: If I've never added a launch image before, then surely this wouldn't be the issue?

Comment: UIKit seems to size the app based on launch image sizes in some cases because *launch images are required app resources*. So yes, if you haven't added one, then it's possibly the issue.

Comment: Ok so a new launch image is in place (opened up the folders - see what you mean now), and the views arn't fixing them selfs. It all seems really odd!

Comment: iOS Simulator can be flaky. Have you tried quit and relaunching it? I know it sounds basic, but I've searched for a bug for hours before that was not actually a bug, but simulator being terrible.

Comment: Yeah I've shut down and re-launched everything.